# Can contrasts and interaction contrasts be identical in linear mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, contrasts

I have a doubt with respect to the estimated marginal means of a linear mixed model.
I performed a mixed model like the one in the example below:

```
library("lme4")
library("emmeans")

model <- lmer(dep_variable ~ covariate * condition + (condition | subject), dataset)
summary(model)
anova(model)
```

After this, I checked the contrasts:

```
emmeans(model, pairwise ~ condition)
emmeans(model, pairwise ~ condition | covariate)
```

I wanted to check which factors (i.e., `covariate` and `condition`) affected my dependent variable (i.e., `dep_variable`). The dependent variable and the covariate were numeric variables, while `condition` was a factor variable with 3 levels.

After performing the model and checking the estimated marginal means, I realized that the estimated marginal means were the same both when I looked at the main effect `condition` and when I checked the interaction between `covariate` and `condition`.

Moreover, I realized that the contrasts of the interaction were centered at the mean value of the covariate (numeric variable).

I have two questions:

Did I make a mistake? If not, can I change the value of my covariate in order to explore the contrasts by "holding" the covariate to another value (not the mean)?

Comment: By default, only one covariate value is used -- its mean. So the two `emmeans` calls you show are guaranteed to yield the same results. That is, it doesn't matter whether you explicitly condition on it or not because the same value is used either way. If you use an `at` specification to specify several covariate values, then you will see an assortment of results in that second call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have interactions, things indeed get more complicated. But what you describe seems valid. That is, you select a *specific value* for the `covariate`, and make the pairwise comparisons for the different conditions using this particular value. Also, because you have fitted an interaction model, note that the main effect of `condition` is interpreted for a specific value of `covariate`, namely for `covariate = 0`.

With that in mind, I feel that your question mainly relates to the use of the **emmeans** package, and therefore, I would suggest having a look at the online documentation. More specifically, in the [Interaction Analysis vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html). I would speculate that `emmeans(model, pairwise ~ condition)` produces results for `covariate = mean(covariate)` because this is often more relevant than `covariate = 0`. For example, say that the covariate is age. It makes more sense to produce pairwise comparisons for `condition` for the average age in your data, than for age = 0 (assuming you have a study on subjects with ages far away from zero).

Comment: It does not use `covariate = 0` by default in any situation. i don't know why you say that.

Comment: @RussLenth I think I said that is uses `covariate = mean(covariate)` because this is more relevant than `covariate = 0`. Nonetheless, as always, there are exceptions to the rule. In longitudinal data where I work, `covariate` is time, and there it makes sense to see what happens at baseline, i.e., at time = 0.

Comment: I know you said that, but earlier you said that covariate = 0 is the custom when it is an interaction model. And I don't know anywhere where that is recommended as a routine analysis.

Comment: @RussLenth what I mean is that the coefficients for the main effect of condition are interpreted for `covariate = 0`. That is, in the model $\beta_0 + \beta_1 cond + \beta_2 cov + \beta_3 \{cond \times cov\}$, the coefficient $\beta_1$, what I called the main effect of cond is interpreted for cov = 0.

Comment: Well, it all depends on the parameterization, but under the default contr.treatment coding, ,(beta_0, bata_2)  together give the intercept and slope for the reference level of cond, and (beta0 + beta_1, beta_2 + beta_3) give the intercept and slope for the other level of cond. So really it is beta_0 and beta_2 that have a context with the covariate being zero.